# How to install GNU Radio on OpenWrt

Tags: openwrt, gnuradio

I have installed OpenWrt in a Virtualbox, i am new to the OpenWrt, could any one guide me how to install GnuRadio on the OpenWrt OS.

Answer (score 1):

Read the GNU Radio Embedded wiki page:

http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Embedded

It is a work in progress, but hopefully gives you some ideas where to start using GNU Radio on embedded devices. We do not support OpenWRT.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a linux, probably running on some ARM processor, so follow the cross-compile instructions on the GNU Radio wiki.

However, it should be noted that most openWRT boxes are basically the least powerful linux devices you find, and running GNU Radio on a device that weak doesn't make much sense at all.